# Dynamo/DB Spring "Not a managed type" hibernate exception

Tags: groovy, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

Spring/DynamoDb Receiving "Not a managed type" Exception

Setup: 
Groovy, Spring 2.1.6, AWS SDK 1.11.59, spring dynamodb 5.1.0.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'platformCalendarController': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'calendarService'; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'calendarService': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationCalendarDao'; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'applicationCalendarDao': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationCalendarRepository'; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'applicationCalendarRepository': 
Invocation of init method failed; 

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: 
class com.thezer0team.shredderapi.model.ApplicationCalendarEntity
```

Troubleshooting: 
Validated Config includes referenced repositories. Reviewed annotations for entity, repository and config.

```
@Service
class CalendarService {

    @Autowired
    PlatformCalendarTransform platformCalendarTransform

    @Autowired
    ApplicationCalendarTransform applicationCalendarTransform

    @Autowired
    ApplicationCalendarDao applicationCalendarDao

    @Autowired
    PlatformCalendarDao platformCalendarDao

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao

    ApplicationCalendarEntity assignNewPlatformToCalendar(PlatformCalendarRequest platformCalendarRequest) {

        PlatformCalendarEntity platformCalendarEntity = platformCalendarTransform.getEntityFromRequest(platformCalendarRequest)

        platformCalendarDao.createNewPlatformCalendar(platformCalendarEntity)

        return applicationCalendarDao.readApplicationCalendarById(platformCalendarRequest.applicationCalendarId.toString())
    }

    ApplicationCalendarResponse getApplicationCalendarResponseFromEntity(ApplicationCalendarEntity applicationCalendarEntity) {


        return applicationCalendarTransform.getResponseFromEntity(applicationCalendarEntity)
    }

    PlatformCalendarEntity createPlatformCalendar(PlatformCalendarRequest platformCalendarRequest) {

        PlatformCalendarEntity platformCalendarEntity = platformCalendarTransform.getEntityFromRequest(platformCalendarRequest)

        return platformCalendarDao.createNewPlatformCalendar(platformCalendarEntity)

    }

    PlatformCalendarResponse getPlatformCalendarResponseFromEntity(PlatformCalendarEntity platformCalendarEntity) {

        return platformCalendarTransform.getResponseFromEntity(platformCalendarEntity)
    }
}
```

```
@Component
class ApplicationCalendarDao {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationCalendarRepository applicationCalendarRepository



    ApplicationCalendarEntity createNewApplicationCalendar(ApplicationCalendarEntity applicationCalendarEntity) {
        return applicationCalendarRepository.save(applicationCalendarEntity)
    }

    ApplicationCalendarEntity readApplicationCalendarById(String id) {
        return applicationCalendarRepository.findById(id).get()
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
@EnableScan
interface ApplicationCalendarRepository extends CrudRepository<ApplicationCalendarEntity, String> {

}
```

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "applicationCalendar")
class ApplicationCalendarEntity {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    String calendarId

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    BigInteger applicationCalendarId

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    String name

    List<ApplicationCalendarEventEntity> events
}
```

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "applicationCalendarEvent")
class ApplicationCalendarEventEntity {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    String eventId

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    String nativeEventId
}
```

This is my initial DynamoDb attempt and I can't see where Spring is failing to scan the above classes.

Comment: Not sure at all, but don't you need a `DynamoDBTable` annotation on `ApplicationCalendarEntity`?

Comment: That was actually a mistake in the original post, thanks for pointing that out. I have both the ```@DynamoDBTable``` on the entities and ```@Repository``` on the repository, though I don't know that I need Repository.

Comment: Did you solve this?